# URLDecoder in android

Tags: php, android

Please see [this link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89).We will be able to send the data by the following code:

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") 
                         + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8"); 

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8"); 

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") 
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") 
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");
```

and then when the `php` file tries to send the string variables using the `echo` command, How can I get the variable values in `php` separately in java variables?

As a visual description, I want such a thing:

```
//in java-> String name = echo "$name" //in php 
//in java-> String pass = echo "$pass" //in php and etc.
```

in existing code in the link we can assign the all input strings only in the one variable java such as `text = sb.toString();`. I want assign for each `echo $variable` in php, one specific variable in java that as the result I can display each of them in arbitrary places in activity. Please explain me on based the link to prevent bewilderment. Thank you.

Comment: echo json_ecode string from php and parse it on android side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following in php:

```
echo "{";
echo "\"name\":\"$name\",\"pass\":\"$pass\"";
echo "}";
```

Use following in java code:

```
String response = ""; // response from php page.
    String name,pass;
    try
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        name = obj.getString("name"); // value of $name
        pass = obj.getString("pass"); // value of $pass
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do read about `JSON` to have better understanding about it.